# Reading CSV data as numbers rather than symbols

Tags: import, csv-format

I am attempting to read some data from a CSV file I have using

```
edgeDistribution = Import["edge_distribution_2.csv", "CSV"]
```

Mathematica will then output

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}
```

as I would expect. However, when I try to access the data using `edgeDistribution[[0]][[0]]`, Mathematica outputs `Symbol` instead of interpreting the numerical data.

Is there something wrong with how am I trying to read from my CSV file? I have attached it [here](https://github.com/cpark25/test/blob/master/edge_distribution_2.csv) for reference in case the problem is with the file itself.

Comment: Part numbering starts at 1, not 0.  Try `edgeDistribution[[1,1]]`

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks!